# .txt in combo box

Tags: java, swing

I am new in the world of programming and am completing a Java programming assignment.  In my assignment I am having a problem trying to display a list of .txt files in a combo box. Can some body help me please? Here is the code that I am trying to use.

```
  DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
  Object list1Selected = list1.getSelectedItem();
  String selected = list1Selected.toString();
  System.out.println(selected);
  String files;

  File folder = new File("/Assignment_Datex/new_destination/msgsend0.txt",
           selected);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
  for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
     if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        listModel.addElement(files);
     }
     list.setModel(null);
  }
```

Comment: Please tell us exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Also, I have edited your post to try to make it more readable, but please let me know if I have changed your intention too greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you call `list.setModel(null);` into the loop? Remove this line and call `list.setModel(listModel);` **after** the loop.